# Swift - unable to connect to open hotspot

Tags: ios, swift, nehotspothelper

I'm attempting to connect to an open Wi-Fi network using the `NEHotspotConfigurationManager` without any luck. I've ensured my app has the proper Hotspot Configuration Entitlement and I'm running on a device that is > iOS 11.

Here is the code I'm using to connect to the open network.

```
// MARK: - Connect to Hotspot
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func connectToHotspot(completion: @escaping APConnectionStatusHandler) {
    let configuration = NEHotspotConfiguration.init(ssid: Constants.hotspotSSID)
    configuration.joinOnce = true

    NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(NEHotspotConfiguration.init()) { connectionError in
        if let error = connectionError {
            debugPrint("Failed to automatically connect to \(Constants.hotspotSSID)")
            debugPrint(error)
            completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            debugPrint("Automatically connected to \(Constants.hotspotSSID)")
            completion(true, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

`connectionError` is populated every time I run this with:

```
Domain=NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain Code=1 "invalid SSID."
```

I'm unable to find any information on what exactly this error message means. The network shows up in the list of networks for the device I'm using. I'm spelling it correctly and the error message is the same regardless of what SSID string I use.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't use Constant.hotspotSSID.

According to the afore-mentioned, I cannot identify what is the 'Constant' or which data type it is.

Here is my thought, try this:

```
            let yourSSID: String = "SSID"
            let configuration = NEHotspotConfiguration.init(ssid: yourSSID)
            configuration.joinOnce = true
            NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(configuration) {
                (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Connect-> Failure!")
                } else {
                    print("Connect-> Success!")
                }
            }
```